# Как присоединить две таблицы [SQL]?

Tags: sql

Хочу написать что-то такое, но увы не работает!

```
SELECT `year` FROM `success` JOIN (SELECT YEAR(now()) as `year`) `a`;
```

Понятно что присоединяю не совсем таблицу, но а как тогда быть?

Comment: Приведите пример данных, которые у вас есть изначально, и пример результата, который вы хотите получить

Comment: Не знаю как тут это отоброзить но могу описать что есть и что хочу увидеть.
Таблица success имеет поля id, year (Упрощенный вариант большего и не надо)
И "таблица" a, которая содержит текущую дату
Хочется увидеть декартовое произведение, то есть обычный JOIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то у нас есть таблица `success` вида

```
id            year
--------------------
1             1889
2             2007
3             3015
```

Мы хотим получить следующий результат

```
year          current_year
--------------------------
1889          2016
2007          2016 
3015          2016
```

Тогда нам подойдёт запрос

```
SELECT `year`, YEAR(getdate()) as `current_year` FROM `success`;
```

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я какой-то велосипед изначально придумал)

Comment: Можно и велосипед:

SELECT success.*, `year` FROM `success` , (SELECT YEAR(now()) as `year`) `a`;